# Messagepack in redis

Tags: c++, redis

I am creating a large map in messagepack using c++.  I need multiple languages to be able to have access to the data.

How would I store this as a string in redis?  Is there an idiomatic way to put this in memory or should I use the following?

```
    msgpack::packer<msgpack::sbuffer> pk2(&buffer2);
    pk2.pack_map(2);
    pk2.pack(std::string("x"));
    pk2.pack(3);
    pk2.pack(std::string("y"));
    pk2.pack(3.4321);
    Redox rdx;
    rdx.connect()
    rdx.command<int>({"rpush", "key_name", buffer2.data()})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sensible depends on what you're trying to achieve. You didn't explain why you're using the Redis List data structure to store your msgpack data, so unless there's some unspecified reason to do so, I'd go with simple Strings.

Also, the example provided does not make sense IMO because you're not providing the key name to rpush into.
*Edit: thanks for correcting the snippet*

Lastly, if you're using msgpack for your data, you can do really interesting things with Lua scripting as Redis provides the cmsgpack library to manipulate packed messages.

Comment: I am storing market data information for real time data.

Comment: Lists' properties that make them suitable for some data and some access patterns, other types are applicable in various cases. Msgpack turns the data practically opaque to Redis. Start by sharing info about the reads you're looking to do perhaps.

Comment: Essentially, in a number of different languages, I want to be able to query market data given some properties.  I want to grab the last 100 items and return all values that meet criteria. I figured I could do lua and msgpack for this.